# Tensorflow: How can I write all items from my dataset object to a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow

I'm attempting to create a data input pipeline according to tensorflow methods.

I have a bunch of CSV files that I want to use for this project.

First I ran the list_files() method to shuffle the filepaths. Then I used interleave() to interleave each line of the randomly selected CSV files. I did some shuffling with shuffle(), now I'm trying to iterate over the dataset and store each element in a numpy array so I can do some preprocessing - but it is only writing one element to the array.

I can't seem to understand why. Here is my code:

```
n_readers=5
dataset = filepath_dataset.interleave(lambda filepath: tf.data.TextLineDataset(filepath),
cycle_length=n_readers)

dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1000)
tweets = np.array([])

for item in dataset:
  item = item.numpy()
  #print(item)
  item = item.decode('utf-8')
  #print(item)
  tweets = np.append([],item)

print(tweets)
```

I'm expecting the array named "tweets" will be populated with all items from the dataset object with this for-loop. However, I am only getting one line from the CSV file, that is, one element.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure your dataset has more than one row?

Comment: My csv files for sure have more than 1 row, but yes, it does appear that the interleave() method isnt behaving accordingly. It's only giving me back 1 row - do you know how to why/ or how to fix this?

Comment: Can you provide some comma separated dummy data to reproduce your error?

Comment: i'm not getting any error messages, its just returning 1 row of the csv file into the array. 
I did try using a while loop to iterate over the dataset object, and it appears that all the data from the csv files are there - it prints them all out

Comment: sure, how do i send it? new here

Comment: Google drive for example